# How to draw into MouseListenerEvent?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, mouselistener

I have following code:

```
        label.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Graphics g=image.getGraphics();
                    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

                    g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {}

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {}           
        });
```

image is BufferedImage object. But when I click by label it won't draw anything. I think that there is problem with threads. How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: There is no problem with threads in any of the code you've shown. You're missing a lot of code (especially your paintComponent override), and showing unnecessary code (all those blank methods). If still stuck, you would do well to take Andrew's advice and create and show an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 3):

**Interactions with the `Graphics` object should be limited to the `paintComponent` method.**

Yes, this is a problem with threads, but not entirely in the way you may think.

All painting is done within the `paint()` method on the component which calls `paintBackground`, `paintBorder`, and `paintComponent`.  Instead of painting to the region in the mouse handler event, you need to set a flag and call `repaint()` on the panel or component you wish to draw this on.

Within this component, overwrite the `paintComponent` method.  Call `super.paintComponent()` and draw what you will when the flag is set.

When you call `repaint()` on the panel, it will mark the component to be painted.  Then, the `paintComponent()` method will be called the next time the Event Dispatch Thread renders this component.  This will add your rectangle to the top of it.

Comment: Does this not apply only when drawing to the Graphics object of a Swing/AWT component? In this case it was stated that image is a BufferedImage, in which case I'd imagine it being acceptable to draw to it from any thread or method. Based on the given code I can however not say for sure what this image is later used for.